# Assign default value when declaring boolean vs using both clauses of an if statment?

Tags: vb.net, coding-style

Which of the following is more readable and preferable?

This, where the default value is assigned in the declaration:

```
    Dim isLastWeekOfPeriod As Boolean = False
    If periodInfo.WeekCount = weekInfo.Week Then
        isLastWeekOfPeriod = True
    End If
```

Or this, where the value is set in the else clause:

```
    Dim isLastWeekOfPeriod As Boolean
    If periodInfo.WeekCount = weekInfo.Week Then
        isLastWeekOfPeriod = True
    Else
        isLastWeekOfPeriod = False
    End If
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Neither.

Write the assignment directly in the initialisation, don’t use `If` here at all:

```
Dim isLastWeekOfPeriod As Boolean = (periodInfo.WeekCount = weekInfo.Week)
```

The parentheses are not necessary but make the assignment-vs.-comparison more readable. By the way, with `Option Infer On` you can also safely remove the type name, it’s obvious from the initialisation expression and the variable name prefix `is`:

```
Dim isLastWeekOfPeriod = (periodInfo.WeekCount = weekInfo.Week)
```

Remember: Short is good (as long as it doesn’t negatively affect readability).

### Rationale

Your first code is acceptable but it does more or less the same as my above code and has four times more lines of code, without any benefit whatsoever.

The second code does the initialisation *twice*: once in the declaration, since every variable is implicitly default-initialised in VB (thus `isLastWeekOfPeriod` takes on the value `False` in the first line). And once in the conditional block after that. Oh, and finally this code is five times as long as mine.

Furthermore, writing `If a Then result = True Else result = False` is *always* doing redundant work. There is no reason not just to write `result = a` directly.

Comment: I would "argue" that in VB.NET, you should have Option Strict On and the line of code would be: Dim isLastWeekOfPeriod As Boolean = CBool(periodInfo.WeekCount = weekInfo.Week)

Comment: Nice answer. @HardCode: Why convert from a Bool to a Bool?

Comment: @Meta-Knight: It's best in VB.NET to use Option Strict just for general purposes. So doing so, it will cause a compiler error if you do not explicitly cast the boolean expression with CBool().

Comment: @HardCode: If an expression is already a boolean, and assigned to a boolean variable, then there is no casting needed ;-)

Comment: @Meta-Knight: It's the VB.NET compiler that will force CBool() with Option Strict On.

Comment: @HardCode Nonsense. The result of an equality comparison expression *is* a boolean. Casting to `Boolean` is redundant. You are right that you should always use `Option Strict On`. I was actually presupposing that, and my code does compile under `Option Strict`.

Comment: @Konrad. What version of VS and .NET? I turned on Option Strict on a project in VS2008, .NET 3.5, and I got errors where a Boolean was being assigned with a bitwise AND (myBool = int1 AND int2). Hmmm, maybe it's the bitwise AND that was the reason Option Strict flagged it as an error.

Comment: @HardCode All versions. Why are you talking about bitwise `And` now? That’s completely unrelated – it’s a *bitwise* operator and as such operates on integer *numbers*. If you want a (boolean) logical operator, use `AndAlso`; but even then your code won’t work because `AndAlso` (logically) excepts booleans as arguments, not integers. Again, this is unrelated to the comparison operator which takes two arbitrary types and returns a `Boolean`.